# Smart-table.js : pagination and filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, smart-table

Currently I am working on [Smart-table.js](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/), which needs following functionality,

- read JSON data from web service
- create table with pagination and filter
- filter may be on single column or global

I read all documentation of Smart-table.js and created example for my requirement which is available in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/51uuaX8fv5e0fcYFbWcp)

```
angular.module('myApp',['smart-table'])
.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$http',function(scope,http)
{
    scope.rowCollection = [];
    http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mr6e")
    .success(function(response) 
    {
        scope.rowCollection=response.d;
    });
    scope.displayedCollection = [].concat(scope.rowCollection);
    scope.itemsByPage=5;
    
    scope.columnCollection = [
        {label: 'Member ID', map: 'memberID'},
        {label: 'Member Name', map: 'memberName'},
        {label: 'Date Time', map: 'dateTime'},
        {label: 'Balance', map: 'balance'}, 
        {label: 'Amount', map: 'amount'},
        {label: 'Remarks', map: 'remarks'}
    ];
    
    
}])
```

But I am not getting expected output (pagination and filter not working). Can any one suggest me solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the scope.displayedCollection line and set the collection to just rowCollection in the html view it will work fine. Check out the Plunkr.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oj5A1M9ixKtGBl9O2c7y?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myApp',['smart-table'])
    .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$http',function(scope,http)
    {
        scope.rowCollection = [];
        http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mr6e")
        .success(function(response) 
        {
            scope.rowCollection=response.d;
        });
        scope.itemsByPage=5;

        scope.columnCollection = [
            {label: 'Member ID', map: 'memberID'},
            {label: 'Member Name', map: 'memberName'},
            {label: 'Date Time', map: 'dateTime'},
            {label: 'Balance', map: 'balance'}, 
            {label: 'Amount', map: 'amount'},
            {label: 'Remarks', map: 'remarks'}
        ];


}])
.directive('stExport',function(){
  return {
      require:'^stTable',
      link:function(scope, element, attr,ctrl){
      element.bind('click',function(){
      alert(ctrl.getFilteredCollection().length);

  })
}
}

});
```

Comment: pagination pages not displayed and when I type something in global search, it filters correctly, but when I clear all text, then not displayed all records.

Comment: I went back and took another look and noticed that you are setting st-table to displayedCollection but you are using ng-repeat on rowCollection. If you change that, then your original code will work. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xa4iqe?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

When using st-safe-src directive, st-safe-src should receive the full collection, while st-table receives the displayedCollection which is the filtered, sorted and paginated result like you have done in your plunker. However when displaying the rows with ng-repeat, you have to iterate on the displayedCollection (the one passed to st-table) as the original collection passed to st-safe-src never will be modified by smart table.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
```